Simplifying hypergeometric function ${}_3 F_2$ with special relationship between parameters
I've come across a generalized hypergeometric function of the form
$$
{}_3 F_2\left(\genfrac..{0pt}{}{h,h,2h}{1+h,1+h};z\right).
$$
Its parameters $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ and $\{b_1,b_2\}$ are expressed in terms of a single parameter $h$, and there's substantial symmetry between them.  I was hoping this would allow me to express this function is terms of simpler functions (perhaps the standard Gauss hypergeometric function ${}_2 F_1$, or even more elementary functions), but I've been unable to find any such simplification.
I've looked through the identities and special cases compiled on Wolfram, but I've been unable to find any that clearly match the form my function has.  The DLMF cites Prudnikov et al. for additional special cases of generalized hypergeometric functions, but unfortunately I do not currently have access to it.
Does anyone know if the function above can actually be simplified in any substantial way?  (I do know that it can be transformed through a quadratic transformation of variable, but I wouldn't consider that a simplification.)

A form of it appears as 7.4.1.5 in the third volume as a difference involving two ${}_2F_1$. Someone else might have a tidier solution, but if not I’ll write it down here, let me know.

Are you referring to Prudnikov?  If you wouldn't mind writing it down, that would be really useful!

It'll take a bit more work than I first noticed, but from vol. 3 of Prudnikov, Brychkov, Marichev entry 7.4.1.5 you have ${}_3F_2(a, b, c; a+1, b+1;z)= (b-a)^{-1}(b,{}_2F_1(a,c;a+1;z) - a,{}_2F_1(b,c;b+1;z))$. Yours would be a degenerate case where $b=a$, but maybe this and limits will help in some way.

That's a useful start, thanks!

Any chance $h$ is bounded or is an integer?  Is $z$ bounded?

$z$ is not bounded, but for my purposes $h \in (0,1/2)$

Using https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/07/01/01/ and https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/07/01/01/
$$_3F_2(h,h,2h;1+h,1+h);z)=\frac{h\Gamma(1+h)}{\Gamma(1-h)\Gamma(2h)}\int_0^1\int_0^1t^{2h-1}(1-t)^{-h}s^{h-1}(1-tsz)^{-h}dtds$$
It does not look friendly in spite of the simple form of $_3F_2$. What we can do for sure is to find asymptotics.
